# How to set offset of ListView's scrollbar from the right

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollbar

**Please read before answering as this may not be the question you think it is**

Here is my ListView

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/ist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/ca”
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/h1”
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Everything is working fine, except the scrollbar apparently has a `paddingRight` or `layout_marginRight` that I didn't set. The scrollbar itself -- not the row items that I populate from the adapter. So what I am seeing is the scrollbar showing up about 10dp from the right edge while the content of my rows fill the screen's width. What I want is for the scrollbar to show up entirely to the right of my contents so that it is not a visual superposition along the z-axis.

Comment: I have seen similar effect in my project and I was setting fastScrollEnabled(true). Removing it solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try playing with `scrollbarStyle`. I've found that `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` works/looks best.

`Controls the scrollbar style and position.`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollBarStyle(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollBarStyle%28int%29)

> public void setScrollBarStyle (int style)
>
> Added in API level 1 Specify the style of the scrollbars. The
>   scrollbars can be overlaid or inset. When inset, they add to the
>   padding of the view. And the scrollbars can be drawn inside the
>   padding area or on the edge of the view. For example, if a view has a
>   background drawable and you want to draw the scrollbars inside the
>   padding specified by the drawable, you can use
>   SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY or SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET. If you want them
>   to appear at the edge of the view, ignoring the padding, then you can
>   use SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY or SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET.
>
> Related XML Attributes android:scrollbarStyle Parameters style    the
>   style of the scrollbars. Should be one of SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY,
>   SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET, SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY or
>   SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET. See Also SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
>   SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY
>   SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET

Comment: `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"` works for me. Many thanks for understanding my question.